# Determining volume cluster size without using GetDiskFreeSpace

Tags: windows, winapi, filesystems

I'd like to programmatically determine the cluster (a.k.a. allocation unit) size of a volume (a.k.a. file system) mounted on a Windows system.  For various reasons, I'd like to find a solution that does *not* use `GetDiskFreeSpace()`.

Are there any FSCTL_xxx or IOCTL_xxx requests that can be used for this purpose?

Comment: If you want a generic solution, you could call FSCTL_GET_VOLUME_BITMAP and count the bits, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DeviceIoControl with `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY`. On input, set the `PropertyId` in the `STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY` structure to `StorageAccessAlignmentProperty`.

That will get you a [`STORAGE_ACCESS_ALIGNMENT_DESCRIPTOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800831.aspx), which contains members for both `BytesPerLogicalSector` and `BytesPerPhysicalSector`. The linked reference page includes demo code to retrieve and display the logical/physical sector sizes for a device.

Comment: Thanks, looks promising. But how to go deeper and retrieve cluster (allocation unit) size for the volume (file system)? Which are built on the top of `physical drive` and its `logical sectors`.

Comment: For NTFS you can use `FSCTL_GET_NTFS_VOLUME_DATA`. I'm not sure how many other file systems you're likely to care about.

Comment: well, at least FAT32 too (as i've noticed already f/s driver handles NTFS and FAT32 no in common way)

Comment: For FAT32 just read the first sector.  Bytes per sector is a word at 0x0B and sectors per cluster is a byte at 0x0D.  See http://home.teleport.com/~brainy/fat32.htm

Answer (score 4):

You need to call [`NtQueryVolumeInformationFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567070.aspx) on the handle of a file that resides on your volume, requesting `FileFsSizeInformation`. You should be able to get this function through

```
GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("ntdll.dll")),"NtQueryVolumeInformationFile")
```

The resulting [`FILE_FS_SIZE_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540282.aspx) structure will have a `SectorsPerAllocationUnit` value and a `BytesPerSector` value available, which, when multiplied, give you the size of an allocation unit (cluster).